# Small doubt about Constrained Least Squares solution

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, computer-vision

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GUbWsXU1mac) video about Camera Calibration and I have a doubt regarding the solution of the following Constrained Least Squares problem
$$
\underset{\mathbf{p}}{\operatorname{min}}\Vert A\mathbf{p}\Vert\ \ \ s.t. \ \Vert\mathbf{p}\Vert^2=1\\
$$
Which is equivalent to
$$
\underset{\mathbf{p}}{\operatorname{min}}\left(\mathbf{p}^T A^TA\mathbf{p}\right) \ \ \  s.t. \ \mathbf{p}^T\mathbf{p}=1
$$
So we define a Loss function $\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{p},\lambda)$
$$
\mathcal{L}(\mathbf{p},\lambda) = \mathbf{p}^T A^TA\mathbf{p} -\lambda(\mathbf{p}^T\mathbf{p}-1)
$$
Taking the derivative w.r.t. $\mathbf{p}$ and find out that we're in front of the well-known *eigen-value* problem
$$
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L(\mathbf{p},\lambda)}}{\partial\mathbf{p}} = 2A^TA\mathbf{p}-2\lambda\mathbf{p} = 0\\
A^TA\mathbf{p}=\lambda\mathbf{p}
$$
The solution of the problem apparently is the eigenvector $\mathbf{p}$ with the **smallest** eigen-value $\lambda$ (minute 7:22 of the video).

My question is: why does the solution has to be the eigenvector $\mathbf{p}$ with the *smallest* eigen-value? Wouldn't any eigen-vector work as well?

Comment: Because the parameter you are looking for is a critical point and this it satisfies an eigenvalue type of equation.

Comment: Pre-multiply the last equation by $\mathbf{p}^T$ and you'll know why.

Answer (score 1):

As your matrix $A^TA$ is by construction real, symmetric, and positive semidefinite their eigenvalues are all non-negative real numbers and it can be diagonalized in an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $e_1,\dots,e_n$ associated with eigenvectors $\lambda_1\geq\dots\geq\lambda_n$. Now we can write any vector as
$$x=\mu_1e_1+\dots+\mu_ne_n$$
With $\mu_1^2+\dots+\mu_n^2=1$. In particular, we have
$$p^tA^tAp-e_k^tA^tAe_k=\lambda_1\mu_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n\mu_n^2-\lambda_k\geq \lambda_k\left(\mu_1^2+\dots+\mu_n^2-1\right)=0$$
Therefore as we know the minimum is an eigenvector and this eigenvector will be the one that minimizes the difference
$$\lambda_1\mu_1^2+\dots+\lambda_n\mu_n^2-\lambda_k$$
And clearly, this will be the eignenvector $e_q$ with minimum eigenvalue $\lambda_q$.